# Using variables in config.xml

Tags: jenkins

I would like to extract values, like paths, which I always use in jenkins configs (jobs and jenkins config.xml) to a variable and use it inside of jenkins configs.

E.g. I would like to use the job-name inside the "custom workspace" job-configuration.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want or something else?

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Building+a+software+project#Buildingasoftwareproject-JenkinsSetEnvironmentVariables

It is possible to extract anything you want through groovy, but is it just the things mentioned above it already exists.

Env-inject is also really nice to set the environment-variables you need:https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin