# How can I use environment variables in jenkins config.xml

Tags: jenkins, docker-swarm

I am running several jenkins services on a docker swarm and I want to use environment variables for some parts of `config.xml`. For example. In my docker service `.yml` file I set a service specific welcome message in environment variable `JENKINS_WELCOME_MESSAGE` and I want to use that message in jenkins `config.xml`:

```xml
<systemMessage>${JENKINS_WELCOME_MESSAGE}</systemMessage>
```

An other example is the configuration of my `docker-swarm-plugin` inside the jenkins service. It needs to know the Jenkins URL for slave agent jar download so I would like to set an environment variable `JENKINS_MASTER_URL` and use it in the docker-swarm-plugin part of `config.xml`:

```xml
<clouds>
    <org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.swarm.DockerSwarmCloud plugin="docker-swarm@1.6">
      <name>Docker Swarm</name>
      <jenkinsUrl>${JENKINS_MASTER_URL}</jenkinsUrl>
```

Is this possible?

When searching fo a solution, I found this question ([Using variables in config.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40605613/using-variables-in-config-xml)). For me the question reads like my question, but the answer is more about using environment variables for in job executions.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same exact question. I wanted to make repository that gets checked out use an environment variable so that I can set it dynamically at the time of Jenkins server setup. I went ahead and just tried it and it works.

I have Jenkins job config like following.

```xml
<scm class="hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM" plugin="git@4.7.2">
    <configVersion>2</configVersion>
    <userRemoteConfigs>
        <hudson.plugins.git.UserRemoteConfig>
            <url>${SEED_REPO}</url>
            <credentialsId>GITHUB_cmsbuilds</credentialsId>
        </hudson.plugins.git.UserRemoteConfig>
    </userRemoteConfigs>
    <branches>
        <hudson.plugins.git.BranchSpec>
            <name>${SEED_BRANCH}</name>
        </hudson.plugins.git.BranchSpec>
    </branches>
    <doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations>false</doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations>
    <submoduleCfg class="empty-list"/>
    <extensions/>
</scm>
```

I have SEED_REPO and SEED_BRANCH defined as global environment variables.